# how to use both onFailure or onStop on akka backoff supervisor strategy?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-persistence

In some of the akka-backoff examples I see that `onStop` is being used and on some others, I see that `onFailure` is being used, but I couldn't see an example where both are used for backoff, am I missing something?  Isn't it common to backoff on both onStop and onFailure?

[onFailure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522429/akka-supervisor-strategy-correct-use-case)
and: [onStop example](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=znc5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=akka+cookbook+backoff&source=bl&ots=2Xjvuyk8Os&sig=beGcX6Puzb8oEZrnPwfjCSDXD8Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifj92EmbTaAhWOblAKHZ31AM4Q6AEIUTAD#v=onepage&q=akka%20cookbook%20backoff&f=false)

```
val supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onFailure( // ok this one is onFailure, how to use both onStop?
    childProps,
    childName = "myEcho",
    minBackoff = 3.seconds,
```

That the supervisor props can be created with either onFailure or onStop, is it possible to use both? how? I haven't seen yet a single example which specifies them both am I missing something?

(in addition, I see I need to specify the child name, am I supposed to guess the child name that has stopped? what if the child name is dynamic?! I don't get the child name meaning.)

Comment: Any given actor is either going to stop or restart on failure, so you only need to use either `onStop` or `onFailure` to create the supervisor props, not both at the same time. The child name is upto you, it's more for logging purposes than anything else.

Comment: When I specify here `childName = "myEcho"` is it applying the backoff supervisor rule only to a child of name "myEcho"? if so how do I apply it to all children of this supervisor?

Comment: Make the child an explicit supervisor which has all the children. Give that a default strategy which will be escalate. That escalation will reach this backoff supervisor which will then work as expected.